# Powershell exit does not stop script from running

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exit

I'm running a Powershell script from a Powershell window.
Inside this script, I'm trying to connect to a service, and wish to stop the script if the connection fails on an exception.
I'm catching the exception but the script refuses to stop, but continues on.
I tried checking error output using **-ErrorAction** and **-ErrorVariable** and many other things.
But the issue is the script does not stop. The script is saved in a .ps1 file and I just run it from the shell windoe".\script.ps1"
Here's the code:

```
Write-Host "Attaching to cluster and retrieving credential" -ForegroundColor Gray
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($clusterrg) -or [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($clustername)) {
    Write-Host "Failed to attacth to cluster. Parameters missing." -ForegroundColor  Red
    Write-Host "Use -clusterreg CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP -clustername CLUSTER_NAME in the command line`n" -ForegroundColor Red
    Exit 1
} else {
    try{
        az aks get-credentials --resource-group $clusterrg --name $clustername
        Write-Host "Done`n" -ForegroundColor Green
    } catch {
        Write-Error $Error[0]
        exit 1
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks you!

Comment: where is it supposed to stop? does `break` make any difference?

Comment: You are using the Azure CLI, not the Azure PowerShell commands. So `try/catch` as well as `-ErrorAction` and `-ErrorVariable` are not supported. You have to check the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable for errors.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - if this fails, i need it to exit out of the script completely, as there is no reason to continue without the successful completion of this code. Thanks!

Comment: @zett42 - thank you. this is exactly what i needed. wish you wrote it as an answer, so i could upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Azure CLI, not the Azure PowerShell commands. So `try/catch` as well as the common parameters `-ErrorAction` and `-ErrorVariable` are not supported. You have to check the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable for errors.

```sh
az aks get-credentials --resource-group $clusterrg --name $clustername
if( 0 -ne $LASTEXITCODE ) {
    Write-Error "Azure CLI failed with exit code $LASTEXITCODE"
    exit 1
}
```

You can find possible Azure CLI exit codes [documented here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/README.md#exit-codes).